# How do i create a majority voting based in two arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Scenario:

I want to create a majority vote system based that takes into account the weight of someone's vote about `N` observations.

So, `M` observers will give their guess about `N` observations, selecting from 3 classes (1,2,3). For each observation, each observer will have a weight associated with it.

Defining:

- `G`: Matrix of guesses per observation / observer (`N` observations × `M` observers);
- `W`: Weights for each observation / observer (`N` observations × `M` observers)

Example:

```py
# 2 observations, 3 observers
G = [[1, 2, 3],
     [2, 2, 1]] 

# Weights (influence) each observer has about each observation
W = [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
     [0.3, 0.1, 0.2]]
```

I need to compute another matrix with shape (`N` observations × `C` classes) that stores the probability of an observation comes from an specific class.

Example using values above:

```py
G = [[1, 2, 3],
     [2, 2, 1]] 

W = [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
     [0.3, 0.1, 0.2]]

P = [[0.1,    0.2,  0.3],
     [0.2, (0.3 + 0.1), 0]]
```

After computing the `P` matrix, I could apply `np.argmax()` row-wise to get the column (class) with highest value:

```py
P = [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], #class 3 has highest value (0.3)
     [0.2, 0.4, 0]]   #class 2 has highest value (0.4)

result = [3, 2]
```

I would like to know how can I combine `G` and `W` to generate the `P` matrix.

Comment: `P` is not a correct data structure and how is the probability calculated?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand why `P` is not a correct data structure, it is a matrix. The probabilities of a sample comes from the summation of all observers based in which class they vote.

Comment: [[`(`0.1,    0.2,  0.3],
     [0.2, (0.3 + 0.1), 0]] this bracket does not have closing part

Comment: Fixed, it was a typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the job done in a vectorized manner by using NumPy's [`indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) and [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html?highlight=advanced%20indexing#advanced-indexing):

```py
In [569]: import numpy as np

In [570]: G = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 1]] )

In [571]: W = np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.3, 0.1, 0.2]])

In [572]: C = 3

In [573]: M, N = G.shape

In [574]: row, col = np.indices((M, N))

In [575]: P3d = np.zeros(shape=(M, N, C))

In [576]: P3d[row, col, G-1] = W

In [577]: P = P3d.sum(axis=1)

In [578]: P
Out[578]: 
array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
       [0.2, 0.4, 0. ]])
```

Comment: i'm getting an error when applying this solution to an especific case: `indexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type`. Do you have any clue where am i missing something?

Comment: It is hard to figure out what the issue is with so little information. Type `G.dtype` in the interpreter. You should get `int32` or `bool`. Otherwise you need to change `G`'s datatipe. Anyhow in order to get further help I would recommend that you post a new question with a full description of that specific case (data, code and traceback).

Comment: Sure, i will take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain why the `G -1` in `[row, col, G-1] = W`, please? Making some tests comparing the guesses from the voting and the real outputs, all answers are shifted by 1, and when i remove `G-1` it does fine.

Comment: You labeled the classes as `1`, `2`, `3`, etc. In Python, indexing starts at `0`. Hence, in order to index the proper element of `P3d` you need to subtract `1` from `G`.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize P with zero values then iterate by observations/rows of G and value of index i.e g[observation][index] if class 1 then add weight[observation][index] from W matrix to P[observation][class]+=weight[observation][index]. i.e in your sample testcase. for row 1. index 0 has value 1 and weight[0][0] is 0.1 so add 0.1 to row 0 and index[class] of P. similarly for index 2 and 3 value are same as index therefore same in P.

Now for row 2, index 1 has class 2 so we add weight of class 2 to p[2][class]+=0.3 and for index 2 class is again 2 so weight of that observer is 0.1 so again p[2][class]+=weight i.e 0.1. for last index class is 1 so p[2][class]+=weight now Our matrix is ready so use np.argmax() for required answer.

Comment: P[1][2] is 0, how?

Comment: Bcz nobody in second observation i.e. G[1][] array chose class 3. Only class 2 was chosen twice and class 1 was chosen once therefore only there weight was added in P array.and for class 3 it was left untouched thatswhy 0.